# Java method that removes all 9's from another number?

Tags: java, methods

I am looking for a Method that removes all 9's from an Integer:

```
public int noNine(int i){
    int res = 0;
    return res;
}
```

Examples:

```
noNine(0)->0
noNine(1991)->11
noNine(99)->0
noNine(19293949)->1234
```

And so on.

No Strings are allowed and no external Methods.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Eddie Texas

Comment: You are going to have to eventually use a String... its gonna look something like this.... `return Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(i).replaceAll("9", ""));`

Comment: Are you sure you are not allowed to convert to a String just to remove the 9's, and then convert back to an int?

Comment: I am NOT allowed to use any String.

Comment: What do you mean by no "extern Methods"?

Comment: What are your initial thoughts on a solution?

Comment: Look into the mod (`%`) operator.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I thik it should be possible to work only with logical operators to solve the problem.

Comment: Why noNine(99)->99? How does it fit the rule of removing 9's?

Comment: @vacsora awww.. my fault.. it should be 0!!

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it is possible that we have to use modulo.. but how?

Comment: What steps did you follow ? What solution did you think of ? How far did you reach ? What problems did you face ?

Comment: @thatidiotguy I believe he means no extra methods, i.e. using a separate method for recursion, and then calling it from his method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
public int removeNines(int n) {
    int returnValue = 0, multiplier = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        if (n%10 != 9) {
            returnValue += (n%10) * multiplier;
            multiplier *= 10;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This loops through all digits and if it is not a 9 it adds it to the output. Tested [here](https://ideone.com/5LDjpQ) and works

Answer (score 6):

```
int removeNine(int n)
{
  int result = 0;
  int mul = 1;
  while(n > 0)
  {
    //check if current digit is 9. if 9 then do nothing
    if(n % 10 == 9)
    {
      n = n / 10;
      continue;
    }
    else
    {
      //if not 9 then add this to result after multiplying by current mul
      result += mul * (n % 10);
      //update mul so that the next digit is added according to power of 10
      mul = mul * 10;
    }
    n = n / 10;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `if (n % 10 == 9) continue;` can't be right. It will get stuck in an infinite loop if that condition is true.

Comment: @PaulBoddington There's n/10 later so it won't get stuck on the same digit repeatedly

Comment: @Monkeygrinder It was wrong before because the `continue` meant the `n = n / 10` wasn't executed. It works now.

Comment: @Monkeygrinder `continue` skips rest of the code inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot about the continue. Sorry guys. Long day. :p

Comment: Can you not shorten this a bit by removing the if-block and inverting the if condition for the else-block?

Answer (score 3):

You could solve this problem in multiple ways

1. Using a for loop to loop through each character
2. Using recursion

I'm going to elaborate on the second technique:

Using this technique, you could solve the problem using integers or strings. I'm going to be using intergers as you said it is a required aspect:

1. Get the last digit using % 10
2. Remove it if it is a 9
3. Recursively check each digit (*Remember to have a base case!)
4. Return final value

   ```
   public int noNine(int i){
       if(i < 10){
           if(i == 9)
               return 0;
           else
               return i;
       }
       int lastDigit = i % 10;
       if(lastDigit == 9)
           return noNine(i / 10);
       else
           return noNine(i / 10)*10+lastDigit;    
   }
   ```

The key takeaway here is that: `n % 10 = last digit of n` and `n / 10 = all previous digits of n`. This happens due to integer division in Java!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version written in a slightly different manner than ritratt just in case you are not understanding his version:

```
public int noNines(int num) {
    int multiplier = 0;
    int result = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
      int digit = num % 10;
      System.out.println("digit=" + digit);
      if (digit == 9) {
        //ignore
      } else {
        System.out.println("Adding " + (digit * (int)Math.pow(10, multiplier)));
        result += digit * (int)Math.pow(10, multiplier);
        multiplier++;
      }
      num = num / 10;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

I left console output so you can see the method in action.